# Bug in Solve (Mathematica 9)

Tags: bugs, version-9, equation-solving

---

**The issue seems to be fixed as of Version 10.1.**

---

Just came across the strangest bug under both *Mathematica* 9.0.0 and 9.0.1. If one enters:

```
Solve[m == p Sin[x] && -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2, x]
```

... then *Mathematica* whirrs and whirrs (running on my Mac Pro with OS X 10.6.8), and doesn't seem to produce any answer (I gave up after a few minutes). But if one changes symbol p to something that 'sorts' earlier than an m, such as an 'a' or 'b', then it works correctly:

```
Solve[m == b Sin[x] && -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2, x]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Obviously, one can add assumptions on p or b to make it solve, but that is not the issue being raised.

Is this just a Mac issue, or are others experiencing the same on other platforms?

Comment: Ah, I've seen this one before... I remember an answer/comment from Daniel saying that this was a hashing problem and cannot be fully fixed, but they address specific and common cases as they encounter them.

Comment: Here's the post I was thinking of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5402214

Comment: Different issue. The hashing one only causes a slowdown in dealing with large, deep expressions. Will investigate.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: FWIW: same behavior in Windows version (Mathematica 9.0.0.0 under Windows 7)

Comment: It seems that changing the letter p to any letter after m will reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 7):

This has been confirmed and reported as a bug (see comments).

Comment: [Related cleanup guidelines proposal](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/916/unanswered-questions-guidelines-proposal)