# Finding all possible solutions to a math mind game

Tags: equation-solving, programming, list-manipulation

In the example below the letters shall be replaced by numbers. The numbers are from `1` to `9`, and each letter has the same number (e.g. `E = 4` all the time. Different letters must have different numbers, so `E = W = 4` is not allowed):

[image: Problem]

If one choose e.g. `E = 4` (and some other numbers for the other letters), it can be easily seen that

[image: Wrong solution]

is not a correct solution because E is in the first two rows 4 but not in the third row!

After some attempts I found that

[image: One possible solution]

is a solution.

I know that there are also some other solutions which solve this problem correctly.
So, my question is: How can I find with *Mathematica (9.0.1)* ALL possible solutions?

My approach is the following:
I create an array with all possible combinations:

```
values = 
Table[{(z*1000 + w*100 + e*10 + i), (v*1000 + i*100 + e*10 + r), 
(z*1000 + w*100 + e*10 + i) + (v*1000 + i*100 + e*10 + r)}, 
{z, 1, 9}, {w, 1, 9}, {e, 1, 9}, {i, 1, 9}, {v, 1, 9}, {r,1, 9}];
```

And then I want to search in the array `values` for the correct combinations. But I have some problems to write a nice searching-program for this. Could anybody help?

I also have doubts if it is a good idea to create such a big `values`-array because I create numbers like `1111` which are forbidden. Is there a way that I can create a leaner array?

Or does anybody have another nice idea how I could find all correct solutions for this problem?

I would be very happy about any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many solutions but not so many that `Solve` wouldn't be the right way to go. 
Since the task has been changed I slightly refine the solution. 
First we find all integer solutions satisfying `1 <= x <= 9` with `Solve`:

```
sol1 = {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n} /. 
Solve[ Join[{1000 z + 100 w + 10 e + i + 1000 v + 100 i + 10 e + r ==
             10000 f + 1000 u + 100 e + 10 n + f}, 
             Thread[ 1 <= # <= 9 & @ {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}]], 
       {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}, Integers];

Length @ sol1
```

> ```
> 2673
> ```

Then we choose only solutions with different digits using `Select[ sol1, Unequal @@ # &]` as proposed by Rojo in the comments. Alternative approach using `{Unequal @@ {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}}` in `Solve` is not recommended since it would be very inefficient.

```
sol = Select[ sol1, Unequal @@ # &]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 7}, {6, 4, 3, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 7}, 
>  {6, 9, 2, 3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 5}, {7, 9, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 5}, 
>  {8, 4, 3, 9, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7}, {9, 2, 8, 5, 4, 6, 1, 3, 7}}
> ```

Let's rewrite solutions in the standard representation:

```
{ 1000 #1 + 100 #2 + 10 #3 + #4, 1000 #5 + 100 #4 + 10 #3 + #6, 
 10000 #7 + 1000 #8 + 100 #3 + 10 #9 + #7} & @@@ sol
```

> ```
> {{4285, 9586, 13871}, {6439, 8932, 15371}, {6923, 7328, 14251}, 
>  {7923, 6328, 14251}, {8439, 6932, 15371}, {9285, 4586, 13871}}
> ```

And check the solutions:

```
And @@ ( #1 + #2 == #3 & @@@ %)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Edit**

The question is not quite clear  whether "The numbers are from `1` to `9`" (see the first line)  or "from `0` to `9`" as suggests the second example. One might also assume that all numbers are from `0` to `9`" except for `f`.

In all cases `Solve` provides quite simple and flexible approach. The case of "numbers are from `1` to `9`" we considered above.

### II

**"all numbers form `0` to `9`"**

```
sol2 = {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n} /. 
Solve[ Join[{1000 z + 100 w + 10 e + i + 1000 v + 100 i + 10 e + r 
             == 10000 f + 1000 u + 100 e + 10 n + f}, 
            Thread[ 0 <= # <= 9& @ {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}]], 
       {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}, Integers];
```

There are

```
Length @ Select[ sol2, Unequal @@ # &]
```

> ```
>  46
> ```

solutions

### III

**"all numbers form `0` to `9` except for `f`"**

Obviously this implies that `f == 1` and impose this condition onto `Solve`, but the former aproach works quite well:

```
sol3 = {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n} /. 
Solve[ Join[{1000 z + 100 w + 10 e + i + 1000 v + 100 i + 10 e + r
             == 10000 f + 1000 u + 100 e + 10 n + f}, 
       Thread[ 0 <= # <= 9& @ {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}], {f > 0}], 
       {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}, Integers];
```

Now we have only

```
Length @ Select[ sol3, Unequal @@ # &]
```

> ```
> 14
> ```

solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and nice approach! But in your case (e.g. `sol[[301]]`)  it would be: e = i = 5. But this is not allowed too (I will make this more clear in my question).
How can I get rid of these wrong solutions?

Comment: Thanks @Öskå for this fantastic add! Unfortunately your code is above my programming knowledge. If you find time, could you please describe shortly how it works?
Perhaps you post also a complete new answer, then I would love to accept yours! Anyway, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @partial81, a simple `Select[sol, Unequal @@ # &]` would fix that

Comment: I knew there was something simpler :D

Comment: @Rojo! Your add is easy to understand! Thanks a lot, that is really a nice idea! I am very happy about yours, Öskås and Artes help! If I find time, I will join the chat to ask questions about the code. Thanks for the invitation and thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Artes...perfect answer now. Very well indeed and it shows the power of Solve if you pick the correct model. Nevertheless, cleverly solved ;)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, on the other hand `Solve` sometimes appears to be less smarter than Reduce (see e.g. this answer [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952) which I couldn't solve with `Solve`) while it is still smarter than `Eliminate` (see e.g. this [Efficient code for solve this equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/efficient-code-for-solve-this-equation/21043#21043)).

Comment: @Artes exactly. you never know which one is the best choice...sometimes/often/toooften. do you have any metrics if and when one of the three suspects is the best pick? (btw, thanks for the links)

Comment: @Stefan Mostly I rely on  my experience, though various documentation pages are helpful, nonetheless they aren't sufficient. I tried to sum up main issues [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129) but often there come up some curiosities like here [Bug in Solve (Mathematica 9)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/bug-in-solve-mathematica-9).

Comment: @IstvánZachar Well, the OP says explicitly "`1` to `9`", though simple modification of this approach would yield more general solutions. It's slightly misleading when the OP is not sure what he is looking for.

Comment: @Artes, Thanks for this fantastic answer and for editing my question! Now I understand the code very well! Sorry for not mentioning from beginning on that e.g. `e=w` is not allowed, I thought this is obvious. To the `1` to `9` or `0` to `9` problem: I am not unsure about this ;-) The book from where I have this mind game uses `1` to `9`. I guess, it does this because it is then a bit more difficult to find a solution by mind (only 6 possibilities instead of 14 or 46). Anyway, thanks again for your help! I learned much about writing nice code and I hope you and others had fun with this game;-)

Comment: @partial81 You are welcome. I'm glad you find this answer helpful. Assuming that numbers are from `1` to `9` One could consider also a bit more involved problem how the number of solutions depends on different permutations of variables `{z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n}` in the initial equations. I find this problem interesting as well.

Comment: Artes, sorry about that, I did not notice `1` to `9` in the post. Now you can extend your answer to other bases than decimal :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Your comment was valuable, thanks. I think it would be constructive to extend this answer as I suggested in my former comment but I don't have time for playing with it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that lets you define terms/sum/entries/constraints generally. Spits out a table where rows are valid values for the corresponding column variables with verification of solutions.

```
ClearAll[z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n];

(* Define alphabet,terms, and sum *)
vars = {z, w, e, i, v, r, f, u, n};
term1 = {z, w, e, i};
term2 = {v, i, e, r};
sum = {f, u, e, n, f};

(* Define Constraints *)
(* minimum and maximun values *)
{min, max} = {0, 9};

(* must all letters assume differing values? *)
mustDiffer = False;

(* Additional constraints, use {} for none *)
conditions = {r > e && n > w > 5 && v > 8 && z > 7};

(* Solve It *)
solutions = TableForm[Select[vars /. Solve[Join[{FromDigits[term1] +
          FromDigits[term2] == FromDigits[sum]},
       Table[min <= zz <= max, {zz, vars}], conditions], vars, Integers],
    ! mustDiffer || Unequal @@ # &], TableHeadings -> {None, vars}];

(* Display Results & Checks *)
If[solutions[[1]] == vars || solutions[[1]] == {}, "No solutions found for given",
 Labeled[solutions, {Length[solutions[[1]]] "Solutions found for given\n", 
    "\nCheck all ok:" (varSave = SymbolName /@ vars; 
      res = And @@ ((ToExpression[ToString[varSave] <> "=" <> ToString[#]]; 
            FromDigits[term1] + FromDigits[term2] == FromDigits[sum]) & /@solutions[[1]]); 
      ClearAll @@ varSave; res)},
   {Top, Bottom}] // Framed]
```

[image]

Here's another way of doing this, a rudimentary hill-climbing solver that is usually *much* faster than using *Mathematica*'s `Solve`, particularly when there are more than two terms and/or terms are lengthy:

```
(* hill climber *)
ClearAll["Global`*"]

terms = {{s, e, n, d}, {m, o, r, e}, {m, o, n, e, y}};
terms = {{f, i, f, t, y}, {s, t, a, t, e, s}, {a, m, e, r, i, c, a}};
terms = {{z, w, e, i}, {v, i, e, r}, {f, u, e, n, f}};
terms = {{f, o, r, t, y}, {t, e, n}, {t, e, n}, {s, i, x, t, y}}

{letters, nonos} = {Union @@ terms, Union@terms[[All, 1]]};
{nonopos, numletters} = {Position[letters, #] & /@ nonos // Flatten, 
   Length[letters]};
check = Total[FromDigits /@ (Join[Most[terms], -{Last[terms]}])];

integers = N[Range[0, 9]];
While[Times @@ (numbers = RandomSample[integers, 10])[[nonopos]] == 0];

{curscore, testcnt, guard} = {Infinity, 0, 100000};
{swaps, bump, bumpthreshold} = {RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {guard, 2}], 
   RandomInteger[200, guard], 4};

mapper := Thread[letters -> Take[numbers, numletters]];

swapper := (keeps = numbers; 
   numbers[[swaps[[testcnt]]]] = 
    numbers[[swaps[[testcnt]] // Reverse]]; 
   If[Times @@ numbers[[nonopos]] == 0., testcnt++; numbers = keeps; 
    swapper]);

While[++testcnt <= guard && curscore != 0,
  keeps = numbers;
  swapper;
  newscore = Abs[check /. mapper];
  curscore = 
   If[bump[[testcnt]] < bumpthreshold, newscore, 
    If[newscore < curscore, newscore, numbers = keeps; curscore]]];

If[curscore == 0, 
 TableForm[{{terms, Round[terms /. mapper], 
    testcnt, (check /. mapper) == 0}}, 
  TableAlignments -> {Right, Right, Right}], "None found"]
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful post! I like it much that I can define with your solution my terms etc. generally.

Comment: @partial81: you're quite welcome. I'd forgotten about this quite amusing question! Take a look at post update I'm making: a rudimentary hill-climbing solver for your kind of puzzles that is generally *much* faster than using MM `Solve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great update! This is really a very nice solution too!!