# Missing zero in the CoefficientList

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

The following list has a length only 10 (not 11)

```
CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2),{x,0,10}],x]
{0, 1, 0, 2/3, 0, 13/15, 0, 76/105, 0, 263/315}
```

It should be

```
{0, 1, 0, 2/3, 0, 13/15, 0, 76/105, 0, 263/315, 0}
```

Compare with

```
CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x),{x,0,10}],x]
{0, 1, 1, 2/3, 2/3, 13/15, 13/15, 76/105, 76/105, 263/315, 263/315}
```

(length of the list is 11)

This is important for an exponential generating functions. Correct is

```
nmax=10; CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x), {x, 0, nmax}], x] * Range[0, nmax]!
{0, 1, 2, 4, 16, 104, 624, 3648, 29184, 302976, 3029760}
```

But from

```
nmax=10; CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2), {x, 0, nmax}], x] * Range[0, nmax]!
```

we get an error:

```
"Objects of unequal length ... cannot be combined"
```

Possible solution is add a missing zero manually, for example:

```
nmax=10; Flatten[{CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2), {x, 0, nmax}], x] ,0}] * Range[0, nmax]!
{0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 104, 0, 3648, 0, 302976, 0}
```

---

*Added after an answer by Mr.Wizard:*

Yes, this is a nice solution (and independent on lenght of list), thank you!. For the final sequence we have:

```
nmax=10; Coefficient[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2),{x,0,nmax}],x,Range[0,nmax]]*Range[0,nmax]!
{0,1,0,4,0,104,0,3648,0,302976,0}
```

But question is, if is also efficient. For big "nmax" is much faster

```
CoefficientList[Series[f[x], {x, 0, nmax}], x] * Range[0, nmax]!
```

than

```
Table[n!*SeriesCoefficient[f[x],{x,0,n}], {n,0,nmax}]
```

Comment: Wait… where is your question here?

Comment: I report a bug (in this case only a minor bug). I found on this website a lot of similar post, for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/

Comment: @Vaclav In that case you should still include the question "Is this a bug?"  Here I don't believe it is one.

Comment: Please see my updated answer with my proposal `seriesCoefficientList`.

Comment: Yes, this is faster:
    {0., 1001}

I tried also (each with a restart of Mathematica)

    Timing[nmax = 1000; Coefficient[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, nmax}], x, Range[0, nmax]]*Range[0, nmax]!;]
    {0.904806, Null}
    Timing[nmax = 1000; Flatten[{CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, nmax}], x], 0}]*Range[0, nmax]!;]
    {0.140401, Null}

Comment: Exactly, I used seriesCoefficientList[big]*Range[0, 1000]! // Length // AbsoluteTiming. But CoefficientList was really much faster than Coefficient.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that `CoefficientList` can take a third argument indicating a total length, and will pad out with zeros to meet that length. This can be used to enforce that the lists being multiplied have the same length.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you.  That appears to be undocumented; do you know why?

Comment: @Daniel: Great! nmax=10; CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2),{x,0,nmax}],x,11] * Range[0,nmax]!  The output is now correct: 
{0,1,0,4,0,104,0,3648,0,302976,0}

Comment: Only note that third argument in CoefficientList can be added in version 10.0, but not in versions 7 or 8 (not tested in version 9).

Comment: In general, in my program above please replace 11-> nmax+1, for example nmax=20; CoefficientList[Series[ArcTan[x]/(1-x^2),{x,0,nmax}],x,nmax+1]*Range[0,nmax]!

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I guess after I was told to implement it, nobody thought to document it. Which in a way is not so bad--  sometimes the opposite happens.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I've now filed a suggestion that this third arg to `CoefficientList` be documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: see the bottom of this post for the best solution.*

The documentation for [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) says:

> The dimensions of the array returned by CoefficientList are determined by the values of the Exponent[poly, var<sub>i</sub>].

```
ser1 = Series[ArcTan[x]/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, 10}];
ser2 = Series[ArcTan[x]/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}];

Exponent[ser1, x]
Exponent[ser2, x]
```

> ```
> 9
>
> 10
> ```

Therefore this is documented behavior, or at least your contention is with [`Exponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html).
It is not looking at the order of the series, only explicit terms:

```
Exponent[#, x, List] & /@ {ser1, ser2}
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

---

Each series is represented by a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) expression.  I think the fifth parameter is what you need:

```
ser1[[5]]
ser2[[5]]
```

> ```
> 11
>
> 11
> ```

```
Coefficient[ser1, x, Range[0, 10]]
Coefficient[ser2, x, Range[0, 10]]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 2/3, 0, 13/15, 0, 76/105, 0, 263/315, 0}
>
> {0, 1, 1, 2/3, 2/3, 13/15, 13/15, 76/105, 76/105, 263/315, 263/315}
> ```

---

### Proposed solution

You expressed concern over performance.  Please try this:

```
seriesCoefficientList[ser_SeriesData] :=
  ser ~CoefficientList~ ser[[1]] ~PadRight~ ser[[5]]
```

Test:

```
big = Series[ArcTan[x]/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, 1000}];

seriesCoefficientList[big] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0010, 1001}
> ```

[Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) revealed an undocumented third parameter of `CoefficientList` that specifies the length to pad to as implemented above, allowing us to define:

```
seriesCoefficientList[ser_SeriesData] := CoefficientList[ ser, ser[[1]], ser[[5]] ]
```