# A bug in Integrate

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis, bugs

```
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

*Mathematica* (wrong) output is (tested under versions 8 and 10.0, took ~ 1 minute of CPU time)

```
10 π
```

The correct value of this integral is `6 π` (not `10 π`).

```
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - 2]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - 2]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]
(* 6 π *)
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - 4]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - 4]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]
(* 6 π *)
```

Version 8 and 10.0.0.0
[image: Version 8 and 10]
Version 7.0.1.0
[image: Version 7]

Comment: What is `y` in your first expression? Because when I try it, I get a `ConditionalExpression[9 \[Pi], -(\[Pi]/2) <= y <= (7 \[Pi])/2]`

Comment: I also get `ConditionalExpression[9 π, -(π/2) <= y <= (7 π)/2]` but I don't think that's right either.

Comment: I added a screenshot, no ConditionalExpression, y is a parameter. Each value of y in a range 0..10 with step 0.1 gives a result 6*Pi. But first integral (with y) 10*Pi, this must be a bug! Same output under versions 10.0.0.0 and 8.0.4.0.

Comment: Version 9 also displays  this wrong behavior

Comment: @Vaclav I noticed that most of your posts here are bug reports.  Please do not do this.  This site is for *questions* only.  If you wish to report bugs, [contact Wolfram directly](https://www.wolfram.com/support/).  **Wolfram will not see bugs reported here. If you only report here, they won't get fixed.**  This site is not affiliated with Wolfram.

Comment: But I already reported one bug in 2012, but still not was fixed. Today I found on this website a lot of posts, where users reported a bugs in Mathematica. See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19322 with an answer "This has been confirmed and reported as a bug". This was motivation for me add a several bugs, which I found.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It would make sense if m.se had a separate section for bug reports. WRI definitely WILL notice them and deal with them, simply because they are on public display and they'll want that list to shrink. With their internal bug reporting mechanism, they pick and choose what they want to fix and what they want to leave as is. I've reported two bugs in 2004, that was 5.1 iirc, and they're still not fixed. Sometimes public display is the only way to get improvements.

Comment: It is the common type of error in Integrate[] which has been discussed many times in this forum:  the indefinite integral (the antiderivative) is not continuous. Hence the definite integral is not the difference of the antiderivative at both ends of the interval. MMA is not able to detect the discontinuity correctly so the remedy is: the user should check continuity and take apropriate measures to adjust the result. Try the simpler example Integrate[2/(2 + Cos[x - y]), {x, 0, 2*Pi}] which gives 0 (Version 8).

Comment: Reporting a miscalculation of `Integrate` on this site is a bit like adding a grain sand to beach.  Still, as the OP notes, such "questions" have been welcomed here generally, although occasionally there really is a question about the result.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: I suggest to give this class of "diffuculties"  with Integrate[] (see my comment here) a name. Maybe Wolfram has already made the classification, and we can publish their choice. Daniel, can you help?

Comment: @Dr.Wolfgang Hintze I have no objection if MSE adds a category such as IntegrateAnomalies. I think it is safe to say, though, that exact definite integrals involving parametrized path singularities are going to be a thorny area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've got a theory....

Let's try to get the antiderivative:

```
Integrate[(1 + 16*Tan[2*x - y]^2)/(1 + 4*Tan[2*x - y]^2), x,
 Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals]
```

`(*returns 5 x - (5 y)/2 - ArcTan[2 Tan[2 x - y]] *)`

Seems legit. You can test with `D[5 x - (5 y)/2 - ArcTan[2 Tan[2 x - y]], x]` and plot or rearrange. This antiderivative is technically correct, but there is a latent `+k Pi` missing where k is an integer.

Using the antiderivative and the fundamental theorem of calculus you can evaluate at `2 Pi` and `0` and subtract the first from last giving `10 Pi`. Yet if you use `NIntegrate` (for some random numerical `y`), it converges to `6 Pi` as expected... so a mystery `4 Pi` has been added that vanished when the singularities in both the numerator and denominator of the integrand became removable as a fraction.

I think what's happening is Mathematica is not accommodating `ArcTan` and `Tan`'s branch cuts at these singularities which will result in an extra `+k Pi` being added on, in this case it's an extra `4 Pi` on top of the true answer. Those branch cut singularities in the top and bottom of the fraction are supposed to disappear (become removable) if we're just dealing with real numbers - yet Mathematica fails to realize this. Why `4 Pi`? Well probably because if you plot the denominator or numerator you'll always see exactly 4 singularities for any choice of `y`. For instance try setting `y` to 5 and doing:

```
Show[Plot[(1 + 16*Tan[2*x - y]^2) /. y -> 5, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
     Plot[(1 + 4*Tan[2*x - y]^2) /. y -> 5, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

If we now force `y` and `x` to only use the real part we get the answer without the mystery `+4 Pi`

```
Integrate[(1 + 16*Tan[2*Re[x] - Re[y]]^2)/(1 + 4*Tan[2*Re[x] -
 Re[y]]^2), {x, 0, 2 Pi}] 

(*Answer 6 Pi *)
```

It's just a theory of mine; I've only recently been studying complex analysis so I may not be right... I definitely think it's a bug now.

EXTRA:
to show that my `D[...antiderivative...,x]` and the integrand are equivalent you can do:

```
TrigReduce[5 - (4 Sec[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2)] == 
TrigReduce@FullSimplify[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2)]
```

Answer (score 7):

*[Edit notice: I'll put the gist up front.]*

**10 π is not wrong**

With proper assumptions given, the integral evaluates as desired by the OP, to 6 π.  Without them, it gives one of the correct values of the integral, 10 π, the one that in some sense is more likely, but without the correct conditions attached.  (One may well argue that is a bug.  However, *Mathematica*'s exact solvers usually give only generically correct solutions.  And beyond that, `Integrate` is a little looser than the others, and that is, I suspect, so that it can reach answers within a reasonable amount of time, when they can be reached at all.  No doubt everyone wishes for more accurate and reliable algorithms.)

By default *Mathematica*'s functions treat variables as complex numbers.  These include functions called by `Integrate`.  Clearly in the OP's call

```
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

the variable `y` should be treated as complex.  What's less clear is whether in the line integral from `x == 0` to `x = 2 Pi`, the variable `x` should be considered real.  In fact, it need not be.  Sometimes it can help to explicitly specify that `x` is real or even `0 < x < 2 Pi`.

```
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2),
 {x, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> -(π/2) <= y <= π/2 && 0 < x < 2 Pi]
(*  6 π  *)
```

In fact this result is valid only when `Abs[Im[y]] < Log[3]/2`.  When `Abs[Im[y]] > Log[3]/2`, the integral is `10 π`.  (So on the basis of the length of the intervals, for most values of `y` the integral is `10 π`.)

Interestingly this is one of those cases where `Assuming` and `Assumptions` give different results:

```
Assuming[-(π/2) <= y <= π/2 && 0 < x < 2 Pi,
 Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]]
(*  10 π  *)
```

One can see the difference in the graph of the integrand. Just by estimating the the average height of the graph, one can see the results `6 π`, `10 π` are probably correct in their respective cases.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[Evaluate@
     Through[{Re, Im}[(1 + 16*Tan[2*x - y]^2)/(1 + 4*Tan[2*x - y]^2) /. y -> a + b I]],
    {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {-5, 10}, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 225],
   Chop[N@
     NIntegrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2) /. y -> SetPrecision[a + b I, Infinity],
      {x, 0, 2 π}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
      MaxRecursion -> 16], 1*^-15]
   }],
 {a, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 200},
 {b, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Checking with `NIntegrate`**

I get `10 Pi` with `y = I`:

```
Block[{y = I},
 N@NIntegrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2),
    {x, 0, 2 π}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
% == 10 Pi
(*
  31.4159 + 0. I
  True
*)
```

Other times, I get `8 Pi`:

```
Block[{y = 1 + I},
 N@NIntegrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2),
    {x, 0, I, 2 π}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
% == 8 Pi
(*
  25.1327 + 0. I
  True
*)
```

And sometimes I can even get `9 Pi`:

```
Block[{y = 10},
 N@NIntegrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2),
    {x, 0, I, 2 π}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
% == 9 Pi
(*
  28.2743 + 0. I
  True
*)
```

However, this is interesting:

```
Integrate[(1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2),
  {x, 0, y, 2 π}, Assumptions -> y ∈ Reals]
(*  ConditionalExpression[(23 π)/3, y == π/2]  *)
```

I think this is certainly wrong.  `NIntegrate` gives `6 Pi` for `y = π/2`.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly, if you follow the hints given in the `ConditionalExpression`s you can get pointed to the right answer although constrained to an overly restrictive region.

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
expr = (1 + 16 Tan[2 x - y]^2)/(1 + 4 Tan[2 x - y]^2);

Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[9*Pi, -(Pi/2) <= y <= (7*Pi)/2]

The wrong answer; however, using the stated conditions

```
Assuming[{-Pi/2 <= y <= 7 Pi/2},
 Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

> ConditionalExpression[6*Pi, 2*y < Pi]

Applying the refined condition

```
Assuming[{-Pi/2 <= y <= Pi/2},
 Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

> 6*Pi

```
Integrate[expr /. y -> 100 Pi, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> 6*Pi

```
NIntegrate[expr /. y -> 100 Pi, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> 18.8496

Answer (score 1):

Integrate and NIntegrate agree on this matter:

```
Table[Integrate[(1+16 Tan[2 x-y]^2)/(1+4 Tan[2 x-y]^2),{x,0,2Pi}],{y,0,10,2}]
(*==> {6π,6π,6π,6π,6π,6π}*)

Table[NIntegrate[(1+16 Tan[2 x-y]^2)/(1+4 Tan[2 x-y]^2),{x,0,2Pi}],{y,0,10,2}]
(*==> {18.8496,18.8496,18.8496,18.8496,18.8496,18.8496}*)

N[6Pi]
(*==> 18.8496*)
```